# Yarn application not getting killed even after Application Master is terminated

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

My application is suffering because of this issue, which is Even after killing the application master, the application is not actually getting killed. Its a known yarn issue [YARN-3561](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-3561). It occurs out of blue, So I have developed a fix in my application and I want to test it. But as of now this yarn issue is not replicating again. Is there any sure-shot way of replicating this issue so I can verify my fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate this by launching the application as daemon process by using setsid utility. By this, even after container was killed, the process kept running.

Comment: Hi Akash, I am facing a similar issue when the driver process is terminating with OutOfMemory error and still the application is not killed and hols up all the resources allocated to it. What was the fix you came up with to remedy this?

Comment: I added checks in the process, that used to run once in 10 mins to poll the status of the (current) yarn application. If the application's status is other than Running, then the process will kill itself.