# Spark driver getting OutOfMemory

Tags: apache-spark, out-of-memory, hadoop-yarn

I am using a spark cluster where I am facing OutOfMemory in the driver program. but after this happens, the application still holds the resources for a long time and other jobs in the yarn queue starve. What is the reson the resources are not freed up as soon as OutOfMemory is hit and the application get killed?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to answer, but let me try. Yarn will try to re-attempt the application 5 times by default. You can change the attempt to 1 or lesser number and check it.

Comment: I see only one exceution from Yarn, after ~30 min or so after the driver terminated with Out of memory. My doubt was, when driver gets killed abruptly does Resource manager know about the failure? I see the resources allocated to the applications are being held during all that time.

Comment: Spark driver is the application master in YARN. when the application master get killed, the resource manager detects the failure and should release the containers. But check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434422/yarn-application-not-getting-killed-even-after-application-master-is-terminated

Comment: Looks like the same issue which is described in the thread. I am facing the same issue of Application not getting killed even when AM is killed.